# Android java. Saved image doesn't show in gallery immediately

Tags: java, android, gallery

I am saving a bitmap . It saves to some root. But doesn't show in gallery. it show in gallery after restarting the device. I tried to send broadcast but it doesn't work for android 4.4.How can I do it to work for api 9-19

Answer (score 0):

The built-in Gallery scans the phones memory when it thinks it's necessary. You can't force it to. Normaly restarting the gallery should help.

**Edit:**

I might have found an intent to refresh the gallery:

```
Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
```

(f is the file wich has been added and should be scanned.) I haven't tried this yet, but it seems legit.

Comment: there must be another way to tell that images has been added